# Connection reset when posting a question

Tags: bug

I'm unable to post a question on the main site, when I click the "Post your question" I get a "Connection reset by peer" error if I try with Firefox and a custom error about "Host not available" from our proxy (I think) if I try from Chrome.

Here is the error from Chrome:

[image: Chrome error message]

Is this something on our network, or is it a problem with StackExchange? How can I test where the problem lies?

I have not checked other sites, as I do not have any other question to ask at the moment.

If it helps, here's the question:

Title

> Is there a term for tables whose record will never be deleted for
>   historical/logging/security purpose?

Body

> Example
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE [Types]
> (
>     [TypeId] TINYINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
>   , [Name] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
>   , [Extension] NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
>   , [ValidFrom] DATETIME NOT NULL
>   , [ValidTo] DATETIME NULL
> )
> ```
>
> When a Type is inserted `ValidTo` is left `NULL`, when a Type is no
>   longer needed it `ValidTo` gets set and the record stops appearing in
>   the application.
>
> This way when a Type is "deleted" referential integrity is not lost,
>   and if a Type with the same name must be added in the future it will
>   have a new ID so record referencing to NewType can be told apart from
>   records referencing OldType.

Comment: Well, there's been five or six questions posted on the main site since you posted this (and some answers). So it's not a global problem. Could be intermittent I guess, or anywhere on the network path between you & SE.